# Get Javascript value using Powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

I have a Javascript value in my Webpart and I want to use this value in my PowerShell script! Is it possible?

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function RetrieveLog() {
    var getItemsUrl = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListName +"')/items?$select= ID,Title,LastDD,Current_x0020_DD_x0020_status&$orderby=Date1 desc&$top=1";


    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + getItemsUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ArrayRetrieved = data.d.results;
            if (ArrayRetrieved.length > 0) {
                console.log(ArrayRetrieved);
                //LICENSES
                for (var i = 0; i < ArrayRetrieved.length; i++) {

                  if (ArrayRetrieved[i].Current_x0020_DD_x0020_status == "Signed-off")

                        $("#LastDD").text(moment(ArrayRetrieved[i].LastDD).format('DD MMM YYYY'));

                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error on Retrieve log");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
}
```

For this, I want to get the value of `$("#LastDD")` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get that specific value from the script since it is only executed in the browser.

The script loads items from a list, checks if a status field is set to "signed-off" and attaches the value of a corresponding date (LastDD) to some element on the page (only for the last item in the list. bug?)

You can at least read the same value with powershell.

Here is an example for how to get list items:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699338/how-to-get-items-from-a-sharepoint-online-list-using-powershell

You would only need to add your own logic.